# How to write If else Properly in react native

Tags: react-native

I have created a Screen. in the screen I got message like "isConnected = true".
Now I want to navigate to another screen only if "isConnected = true" else I want to show message like please connect to internet. so what should I write in if else

here is my code

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { View, Text, Button, Alert, Platform, alert } from "react-native";
import {useNetInfo} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

export const NoConnection = ({navigation}) => {
  const netInfo = useNetInfo();

  if (condition) {
    
  } else {
    
  }
 return (
    <View>
       <Text>Type: {netInfo.type}</Text>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the condition and navigate accordingly.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { View, Text, Button, Alert, Platform, alert } from "react-native";
import {useNetInfo} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

export const NoConnection = ({navigation}) => {
  const netInfo = useNetInfo();

  if (netInfo.isConnected) {
     // navigation -> go to other screen
     return null;  
  }
 return (
    <View>
       <Text>Type: {netInfo.type}</Text>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: what should I write in condition

Comment: Check the above answer.

Comment: wouldn't `useEffect()` be a better solution in this case?

Comment: @sandmann I don't think so. Even if the user is connected, the first render will occur, if placed in `useEffect` which means the user will see the flash of the message.

Comment: Ok thanks But Now How I test That if It is working Or not Because if I disconnect from wifi then my expo will not run so how could I test for No internet case

Comment: I guess your phone has its hotspot on which your computer is connected to, that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I think You not getting my question. I want to say that. My laptop And My Mobile Is connected to same router trough wifi. so Now I want user cant navigate to next screen when there is no internet connection. so how I could test for that case Now. I want user To stuck At No internet Connection screen